# Authentication failed with Jenkins using python API

Tags: python, authentication, jenkins

I am trying to  create a job using the python api. I have created my own config, but the authentication fails. It produces an error message: 
`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 415, in create_job
    self.server + CREATE_JOB % locals(), config_xml, headers))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 236, in jenkins_open
    'Possibly authentication failed [%s]' % (e.code)
jenkins.JenkinsException: Error in request.Possibly authentication failed [403]`

The config file I have created was copied from another job config file as it was the easiest way to build it:

I am using the `import jenkins` module.

The server instance I create is using these credentials: 
`server = jenkins.Jenkins(jenkins_url, username = 'my_username', password = 'my_APITOKEN')`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Jenkins version do you use? Do you have admin privileges or other?

Comment: I am using jenkins ver 2.46.2. How would I be able to check if I have admin privileges?

Comment: An admin can check that for sure in Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security.

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 is basically issued when the user is not allowed to access the resource. Are you able to access the resource manually using the same credentials? If there are some other admin credentials, then you can try using those.

Also, I am not sure but may be you can try running the python script with admin rights.

Comment: Yes, I can get job info, and other job configs. But just stuck in trying to build the job...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know for security reasons in Jenkins 2.x only admins are able to create jobs (to be specific - are able to send PUT requests). At least that's what I encountered using Jenkins Job Builder (also Python) and Jenkins 2.x.

Comment: Thank you for your input! yes it is an admin user, but there was still authentication problems... resorted to post requests instead of the python api library